# Installation of cloudbees toolkit fails

Tags: cloudbees

I am getting following error while installing it

I already have git installed on  eclipse

Help!!!

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: CloudBees Toolkit SVN Support (**SUBVERSIVE MUST BE INSTALLED!!**) (Optional) 2.0.2.201307232010 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.subversive.feature.group 2.0.2.201307232010)
  Missing requirement: CloudBees Toolkit SVN Support (**SUBVERSIVE MUST BE INSTALLED!!**) (Optional) 2.0.2.201307232010 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.subversive.feature.group 2.0.2.201307232010) requires 'org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Am I really suppose to install subversive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are not, indeed the SVN support is optional: you could just not install the Cloudbees svn support unchecking it before the installation.

But if you decide to proceed with the installation of the SVN support, then yes you would need subversive.

Comment: thanks, later i figured this out by unchecking both subversive and subclipse.